# Python: How to control a delay switch with timer while script keeps running

Tags: gpio, python, led

I am trying to set up a circuit that will operate my water-boiler through a push-button.
The result i am looking to achieve is:

- While Boiler is off:

  - Button Press: Turn boiler ON, then turn OFF after 10 minutes
  - Button Release: do nothing
- While Boiler is off:

  - Button Press: Turn Boiler OFF AND cancel the 10 minute timer set before.
  - Button Release: do nothing

As im new, i have put together a script using online walkthroughs and tutorials which does turn the switch (a small led for now) ON and OFF on button presses but, unfortunatelly i cant incorporate the 10 minute delay inside my script.

I am using the sleep() command which puts my whole script to sleep and as a result i cannot operate the Turn OFF function while the status is ON.

I am obviously missing something, so i am turning to you for help in order to point me to the correct code or tutorial.
Also, any other constructive criticism on my code is more than welcome!
Here is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import datetime
import time

def my_callback(channel):  
    if GPIO.input(8) == GPIO.HIGH:
        print('\n▼  at ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        if GPIO.input(7) ==0:
             GPIO.output(7, 1)  
             print('lights on')

             time.sleep(5) #Here is the delay in the script that does not produce the desired result
             GPIO.output(7, 0)  
             print('lights off')

        elif GPIO.input(7) ==1:
             GPIO.output(7, 0)  
             print('lights off')
    else:
        print('\n ▲ at ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print('button released')

try:  
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(8, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=500)

    message = raw_input('\nPress any key to exit.\n')

finally:  
    GPIO.cleanup()

print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: This https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66639/python-one-momentary-switch-led-and-a-shut-off-timer?rq=1 is similar.

Comment: Hey @Joan thanks, it is indeed similar, i just tested it and it's working fine. I would like to know how to do it without using the pigpio lib though. Is there some way to modify my current code?

Comment: You can certainly achieve the same with RPi.GPIO.  I suspect you'd need to be using add_event_detect.  You'd have to use a Python timer for the watchdog as RPi.GPIO does not have an equivalent.  Perhaps have a look at the gpiozero answer as that will use RPi.GPIO as the back end by default.

Comment: Okay then, seems ill go with the pigpio solution, since it seems to be working fine.  Should i delete this question? or should i answer it myself to lead to the other solution?

Comment: I've closed it as a duplicate, if you are happy with the other answer.  If not and you'd like this reopened, just leave a comment @goldilocks.

Comment: It's fine like this, i went with the pigpio solution, thank you.